# How to Reset Meteor Run Config?

Tags: meteor

Strangely, I have an app that persists in thinking that there is a reference to a Google font when that font has long been removed. Specifically, after the project is built, I see the call to the font in the file:

```
./.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/61ea...u87.css
```

But:

```
$ meteor reset
Project reset.
$ grep -ir 'fonts.googleapi' .
$
```

At this point there is **not** a reference to this url in my codebase. (I tried many different searches.) And yet:

```
$ meteor
[[[[[ ~/Code/someapp ]]]]]

=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Started your app.

=> App running at: http://localhost:3000/
^C
$ grep -irl 'fonts.googleapi' .
./.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/61eaf2753d01cceaf6b5bda9e537427d213346eb.css
./.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/61eaf2753d01cceaf6b5bda9e537427d213346eb.css.map
```

The .css and .css.map files both contain a reference to this google font:

```
$ grep -B4 -A2 'fonts.googleapi' ./.meteor/local/build/programs/web.browser/61eaf2753d01cceaf6b5bda9e537427d213346eb.css
 * http://opensource.org/licenses/MIT
 *
 */ 

@import 'http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Lato:400,700,400italic,700italic';

/* Copyright (c) 2014 ...
$
```

This `@import` is the exact line that I previously pasted from google into my less file but, without doubt, I removed it and it no longer exists. But it persists in the build, how on earth is this happening!? Where is it getting it from? And, more importantly, how can I reset this project to remove this reference?

Comment: so sounds like the reference still exists somewhere in the code or packages?

Comment: Do a grep for the font name

Comment: Yes, it exists in the file listed.

Comment: try `grep -iRl 'fonts.googleapi' .` -- it might be used in a package

Comment: Actually, that's the same command I already ran (`R` === `r` and `l` is mostly a display option). It's really, really not there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try removing The whole `.meteor/local/build` directory (after shutting down all Meteor instances) because it gets regenerated anyway.

Comment: Also throw away all package .build directories ```find . -type d -name '.build*' -exec rm -rf ${basename} {} \;``` from within your app root

Comment: Thanks, but actually `meteor reset` already removes the `.meteor/local` directory and @MarcodeJongh, I tried this but, still, my ghost font still returns. Very mysterious, hugely frustrating.

Comment: Maybe another package is importing the font? Try looking in `~/.meteor/packages/`

Comment: Turns out it was a package. It was using the Exact Same Font I had already added and doing it by building the url using less vars to throw me. Myeh, this isn't a very useful question, my problem was mostly bad luck, but thanks for the pointers anyway. Here you go, 50 rep for your time.